# react native functional component useState not Updating

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-functional-component

this is my state object .

```
 const [track_record, setTrackRecord] = useState({
    id: '1',
    name: '',
    date: '',
    time: '',
    start_address: '',
    end_address: '',
    distance: '0',
    duration: '0',
    avg_speed: '0',
    max_speed: '0',
    min_speed: '0',
    coordinates: [],
  });
```

here is the function where I am updating it.

```
 setTrackRecord(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      name: `Track ${tracks.length + 1}`,
      date: moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
      time: moment().format('hh:mm'),
    }));
```

every time I console it ut has the same values.

Comment: if console it right after `setTrackRecord(prev => ({ ... }))`, you're not gonna see any changes because state setter function is async.

Comment: @Layhout console was in useEffect and dependency array was passed

Answer (score 0):

You can set prev data as it is with track_record and append other data with it's updated value like below:

```
setTrackRecord({
      ...track_record,
      name: `Track ${tracks.length + 1}`,
      date: moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
      time: moment().format('hh:mm'),
    });
```

Comment: tried name bit not working

Comment: Could you show me whole code? including your tracks and moment.

Comment: okay. it has been solved. the issue was with react-native-maps poly line , but it was crashing here